# Visual Studio Error with SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-express, ssms-2017

[image]

So when I try to attach my Database tp Visual Studio it does this.

I have deleted LocalDB from my system as we told me it would be useless but it might have been wrong?

I use Visual Studio Community 2017
and SQL Server Express 17

Sql Server Management 17

and SQL Server Configuration Manager 2017

so everything is 17 and  I don't understand why it doesnt work.

Comment: Can you share your string connection?, please

Comment: `LocalDB` isn't _"useless"_  and it's the default used by Visual Studio for development purposes. You'll have to adjust your [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), as the error says, to Sql Express.

Comment: @EdSF When  Ipress Refresh, my Database does nto appear

Comment: @henocsalinas I now use SQL Server Connection string, although when  I hit refresh it doesn't show up my SQL Database

Comment: Do you see your server in SQL Server Object Explorer?

Comment: I think you'll need to provide more details because it's a guessing game. Provide your connection string as previously requested. More questions: Can you see your server _and_ database that you're referring to using Sql Svr Manager? Is it running? Have you tried reinstalling/fixing LocalDb (now that you know it's not "useless")?